# How to get the whole source code from a web page with selenium / webdriver?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I use this python program (usually) successfully for webscraping.
It gives me not only the page's source code but also the code which is hidden behind Javascript.
However, it does not work as desired on this particular website. Information is missing.
It does not seem to be a timing problem.

```
from selenium import webdriver

url = "https://www.youbet.dk/sport/fodbold/"

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='D:/Programme/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe',options=options)
driver.get(url)
```

After execution, driver.page_source contains the code.

I am interested in the text on the buttons (team name and a number).
Right-clicking and inspecting a button in Chrome gives me something like the following code which contains the information I am looking for (here "Villarreal" and "1.51"):

```
<button class="rj-ev-list__bet-btn  rj-ev-list__selection-0ML54283820_1" data-uat="button-ev-list-bet-btn"><div class="rj-ev-list__bet-btn__inner " data-uat="div-ev-list-bet-btn-inner"><div class="rj-ev-list__bet-btn__row" data-uat="div-ev-list-bet-btn-row"><span class="rj-ev-list__bet-btn__content rj-ev-list__bet-btn__text" data-uat="ev-list-ev-list-bet-btn-text">Villarreal</span></div><div class="rj-ev-list__bet-btn__row" data-uat="div-ev-list-bet-btn-row"><span class="rj-ev-list__bet-btn__content rj-ev-list__bet-btn__odd" data-uat="ev-list-ev-list-bet-btn-odd">1.51</span></div></div><span class="rj-ev-list__bet-btn__arrow-up"></span><span class="rj-ev-list__bet-btn__arrow-down"></span></button>
```

But this does not show up in driver.page_source.

How can I access this information using python and selenium?

These did not help:

```
* Adding time.sleep(10)
* Adding driver.implicitly_wait(10)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.youbet.dk/sport/fodbold/"

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get(url)
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'rj-ev-list__bet-btn__inner')))
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
mydivs = soup.find_all("button", {"class": "rj-ev-list__bet-btn"})
alldata = [[div.find("span", {"class": "rj-ev-list__bet-btn__content"}).text,
            div.find("span", {"class": "rj-ev-list__bet-btn__odd"}).text] for div in mydivs]
print(alldata)
driver.quit()
# [['Fulham', '2.55'], ['Uafgjort', '3.40'], ['Leeds', '2.80'], ['Real Betis', '1.83'], ['Uafgjort', '3.65'], ['Levante', '4.55'], ['Parma', '2.40'], ['Uafgjort', '3.10'], ['Genoa', '3.35']]
```

The problem with your approach:
You were close. The issue with the delays that you added to your code were they didn't relate directly to the visibility of the element (maybe ten seconds of wait time wasn't enough). To combat the issue, in this code, I used the more specific WebDriverWait (additional resource: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/explicit-waits-in-selenium-python/)

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located(
(By.CLASS_NAME, 'rj-ev-list__bet-btn__inner')))
```

to wait for the presence of all the elements in the class. The code solution worked for me. Tell me in the comments if you have any issues.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That solved the problem and you gave me valuable insights for future projects.